# Are there any safe places to store my unneeded weapons and shields?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I've found some real nice weapons and shields, but, honestly, I don't really need these 20 damage plus flame blades and soldiers bows and such to take care of most of the low level baddies I'm fighting right now. Since inventory space is at a premium early on though, it's tough to carry them around and also have room for the simpler broadswords and such I actually use to kill ordinary mobs.

I know I can turn in Koro Seeds to increase my inventory space, but until I can do that, is there anyplace I can safely drop some nice weapons on the ground and have them not disappear?

Comment: i never figured out how to get a house, but I bet you could store them there.

Comment: @Seiyria You can start the house quest in Hateno village.

Comment: However, I haven't finished said quest, so I dunno if there's some permanent storage there or not.

Comment: @Powerlord You can buy 3 holders each for weapons, bows and shields.

Answer (score 23):

### Yes

Once you purchase the house in Hateno Village for 3,000 rupies and 30 bundles of wood, you will get one weapon rack in that house which allows to store one weapon in it. Though I haven't tested it in the long run I'm sure that the weapon you put in will not disappear when you come back.

You can then buy more furniture from the same person you bought the house from, allowing you to get more weapon racks among other things.

Comment: You can spend even more rupees to get three weapon racks in total as well as three shield racks and three bow racks. (Cost 100 rupees each.)

Comment: This can also neatly be used for flavour. There's nothing like coming home and being greeted by the light-up of 3 different elemental blades.